# How can I refresh my razor view on AJAX post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Helo all,

I am able to post to controller using ajax.post, but on success how can I make my view refresh with new data.

Do I need to usn @Html.BeginForm to do this?

This is my view.

```
<div>
    <p>Order lines allocates to <b>@Model.Name (@Model.Code) </b>
</div>

@if (Model.OrderLineAllocations.Any())
{
    
    @grid.GetHtml(
             columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column(header: "Dispatched", style: "row-selector", format: @<text><input name="chkSelected" class="myCheckbox" onclick="expandableEvent(this)" type="checkbox" value="@item.IdAllocation" /></text>),
                 grid.Column(header: "Order Ref", format: item => item.OrderLineItem.OrderLine.Order.OrderRef)
                 ),
             tableStyle: "expandable-table",
             rowStyle: "expandable-master-row",
             htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridLineAllocations" })
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidUnselectedValues" name="hidUnselectedValues" />
    
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Dispacth" id="btnDispacth" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Revert" id="btnRevert" />
    
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("No records found....");
}
```

And this is my ajax post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    unSelected = [];
    $("#btnDispacth").click(dipatchAllocations);
    $("#btnRevert").click(revertAllocations);
});

function dipatchAllocations() {
    var objInputEmail = $("#hidUnselectedValues");

    if (objInputEmail != null) {
        var id = objInputEmail.val();
        if ((id != null) && (id != "")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Batch/GetData',
                data: '{ "allocationId" : "' + id + '","batchId" : "' + @Model.Id + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                traditional: true,
                success: subscribed,
                error: errorInSubscribing
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a valid email address in order to subscribe.');
        }
    }
};
```

This is my controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(long[] allocationId,long batchId)
{
    var model = context.GetData(batchId)
    model.Name = "asdaksdjaksdj";
    return View("Finalize", model);
}
```

I am having some idea, I have to do that on success call back. But I am not sure how to bind my updated model to the view at client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple "rebind" method inside mvc, it's still html, css and js at the end.
I see 2 options to achieve desired behaviour.

#### option 1. Override rendered content with the result of POST

In this case your View will look similar to:

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <p>Order lines allocates to <b>@Model.Name (@Model.Code) </b>
  </div>
  ...
  else
  {
    @Html.Raw("No records found....");
  }
</div>
```

On javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Batch/GetData',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }
});
```

#### option 2. Fill rendered html from javascript on every load

This will require to move Razor logic to javascript.
Your view will look like:

```
<div>
    <p>Order lines allocates to <b id="NameAndCode"></b>
</div>
```

And javascript will fill the gaps:

```
$(function(){
  var model = {
    NameAndCode: "@Model.Name (@Model.Code)"
  }

  fillView(model);

})

var fillView = function(data){
  $('#NameAndCode').html(data.NameAndCode)
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Batch/GetData',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        fillView(data);
    }
});
```

It's just a small piece just to show the idea.

It depends on case which option to choose.

Comment: I have tried first option, bt it replacing div html with complete view html. I think it first approach I should go for a partial view and replace div html with partial view html.

Comment: With partial view your first suggestion working fine. Thanks.