# MVC how to include a view that does not have layout info

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to reference a view, but do not want all the header and footer that comes with the view because the viewstart references layout page.  When I have a popup, it also shows the menu items in the header.  Is there a way not to include the layout.cshtml?

Comment: Do you have some code or example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 3: How to render a view without its layout page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318385/mvc-3-how-to-render-a-view-without-its-layout-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layouts can be specified directly in the view or based on the caller.

For example if your `ActionMethod` returns like this:

```
return View();
```

The view will be rendered with the layout. However if the `ActionMethod` returns like this:

```
return PartialView();
```

Then the rendered view will not have a layout.

However, this can be overridden in the view itself. In your view, if `ViewBag.Layout` is null the layout will not be included. Inversely, if `ViewBag.Layout` has a value that layout will be used, reguardless of how the view is called. For this reason, most views do not set `ViewBag.Layout` directly, and leave it up the the caller to specify the intent.

Hope his helps.

Comment: This Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is explicitly set layout to null.

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the header of the view

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Or something like that