# Do not want to load layout page every time in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc web application I want to generate dynamic menu. I want to generate it only first time when a user get log in but not every time when a user go to another view. I want to put menu generated code in layout cstml. But as I know layout refresh each time. Is there any way to solve the issue. Please help me. I am new in mvc. advance thanks to all.

Comment: No you can't do like that. Better cache the menu items in temp storage like session/cache and construct it

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the content of the page in ajax div. Then, each time update the div only.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition in the each view where you do not want to load the layout.cshtml page.

[MVC 3: How to render a view without its layout page when loaded via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318385/mvc-3-how-to-render-a-view-without-its-layout-page)

otherwise you can also set another layout view where menu control is not there and check if first time user logged in then load menu layout else another layout.

Comment: I want to put menu in layout. When I click another page using menu item the layout will remain same but the corresponding page will be loaded.

Comment: use another layout and apply that new layout in your corresponding pages, @{
Layout = "~/Views/Home/newLayout.cshtml";
}

Answer (score 0):

just insert

```
﻿@{
Layout = null;
}
```

on top in your view where you do not want layout

Comment: If I put layout=null then how I get the menu? Because I want to put menu in layout.

Comment: I want to put menu in layout. When I click another page using menu item the layout will remain same but the corresponding page will be loaded.

Comment: so you want SPA then you need to use knockout or angularjs  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

Comment: in this mvc you and insert partial view in different div and hide that div and on click of specific menu show that div

Comment: This answer is valid by itself. if you want to exclude the base layout and make your own page with different html structure. It worked in my case.